# php-database connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to connect my php code with the mysql database in localhost.Here is my php code:

```
  <? php
     echo "hi";
     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","*********");
     if(!$con)
     {
          die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
     }
     mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);
     mysql_query("insert into my_table(firstname,idnumber) values ('$_post[firstname]','$_post[idnumber]')");
     echo "'hi ur name is ('$_post[firstname]')";
     mysql_close($con);
     ?>
```

What should i do? and also when i am running the php code it is also not echoing the "hi" statement {echo "hi"}. Is that a connection problem?

---

I got the result. 
Now whenever am entering the data in the form,the table shows a row is updated but the fields have 0..not the entered data.

Comment: Also, google for 'sql injection' - your code is vulnerable to it and you'd might as well learn to avoid issues like these.

Comment: As an aside also consider using PDO instead. You get a lot for free if you use them.

Comment: i just installed sql.I have no idea about PDO and 'sql injection'. Will they solve the connection problem?

Comment: Are you running this on a linux or a windows platform?

Comment: am running on fedora14 and using httpd...

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php  //No space between ? and php

?>
```

Try,

```
<?php

 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","*********") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("my_db",$con) or die(mysql_error());

 $result=mysql_query("insert into my_table (firstname,idnumber) values ('$_post[firstname]','$_post[idnumber]')");
 if($result)
    //success
 else
    //not success
?>
```

Comment: That was the answer I was just about to give, but I refreshed the page right before :)

Answer (score 0):

please check

> short_open_tag = On
>   in your php.ini

Comment: it was off. I chnaged it to on state.What is this usually used for?

Comment: when you make in "ON" you can use short tags like <? ?> and if it is OFF you have to write php tags in full tags like follows <?php ?>

Comment: just noticed in your code  <? php there is a space between <? and php it cound be fatal error when runs on apache

Comment: That i just rectified.But same problem still prevails.

Answer (score 0):

if you running on xampp. just weather your engine is running mysql or not, and check the syntax to be more clear
Ex: mysql_query("insert into my_table(firstname,idnumber) values ('". $_post['firstname']."','.".$_post[idnumber]."')");

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try`<?php echo "Hello"?>`, If this wont print hello then there is a problem with your PHP installed in your local machine. Also try this

```
<? php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","*********")  or die(mysql_error());
 if(!$con)
 {
      die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);
 mysql_query("insert into my_table(firstname,idnumber) values ('Name','12')") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

The above code should insert Name and id into your database table.

Comment: I guess there is a configuration issue.It is not echoing any string.Can you suggest me what to deal with that.

Comment: Well did it echo hello when u tried  <?php echo "Hello"?>?? If not reinstall php